# Not having "Chapter" appear in chapter names

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, naming, amsbook

If, in `amsbook`, I write something like

```
\chapter{My great chapter}
```

it appears in the text as

**Chapter 1. My great chapter**

I would like to make it appear simply as

**1. My great chapter**

Anyone have any suggestions? It would be great if it reflected the same change in the ToC too.

Comment: Actually it doesn't display the way you mention. It displays chapter in small-caps (by default) above the title (in **bold**). For future reference, it's always best to provide a fully-compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: What about `\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}`?

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thanks. I didn't mind using \chapter*, when no number appeared, but then, for whatever reason, \sections were numbered continuously, rather than being re-set inside every chapter.

Comment: If this is what you were after, then I will turn my comment into an answer. Nevertheless, for future reference, you may consider adding a MWE as Werner suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to redefine the command `\chaptername`. Here is a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228):

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{My great chapter}

\end{document}
```

For more advanced customization, you may also be interested in packages such as [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/). Note that there may also be customization possibilities built-in the `amsbook` class that I am not aware of (for instance `memoir` provides such abilities).

EDIT: as noted in the comments, one should in fact be a little more careful because of the presence of an `\enspace` in `@makechapterhead` in the class `amsbook.cls`. Perhaps the best option to redefine the `@makechapterhead` command as a whole is to use `etoolbox`, as egreg suggests:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\uppercase\@xp{\chaptername}\enspace}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that the title will have the number not centered by moved to the right by \enspace and that is noticable (if you look for it).

Comment: Open `amsbook.cls` and search for `@makechapterhead`. There you'll see `\uppercase\@xp{\chaptername}\enspace\thechapter}`. So, defining `\chaptername` as empty will still produce an enspace. You need to redefine `@makechapterhead`.

Comment: one could be absurdly devious about getting rid of the `\enspace` by redefining `\chaptername` as `\ignorespaces`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with the `etoolbox` package:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\uppercase\@xp{\chaptername}\enspace}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{showframe,lipsum} % just to get a good picture

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\chapter{A chapter title}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]