# How to get rid of "chapter"?

Tags: sectioning, chapters

[image]

This picture shows my actual chapter design. It contains the Norwegian text "Kapittel" for chapter, and I want to get rid of it. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: [Change the word “Chapter” to something else](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30757/change-the-word-chapter-to-something-else)? And also [Not having “Chapter” appear in chapter names](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81692/not-having-chapter-appear-in-chapter-names).

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. Which `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: Please also indicate if you use `babel` and/or `polyglossia`.

Comment: Did you check [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81692/not-having-chapter-appear-in-chapter-names)?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the titlesec package to tweak this page and remove "Chapter 1".

With a litle sample inspired from page 23 of [titlesec documentation](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{20pt}{\Huge}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My chapter title}

some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. some text. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. It would be nice if you added a small (compilable) example, demonstrating how to do it as well.

Comment: This removes the chapter number too - the poster wants to retain that and just remove the word `Kapitel`.

Comment: To retain chapter number uses : \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}

Comment: @sebtic: Thank you! The above line of code leads to "1 \n 'Chaptername'". How can I remove the linebreak and make it look more like a section header? (I'm using a beautiful book class, though I'm closer to writing an article actually.)

Comment: Ah, got it.
`\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\thechapter \quad  \Huge}` does the trick for me