# Settings for Babel package

Tags: babel

The code below is for a part of a document, I have a number of issues:

- The file only compiles upon removing either `fancyhdr` settings in the preamble, or upon removing the title page (which I borrowed from another post) in the front matter, but both in the same file do not work and give the error:

  > warning (node filter): error: ...2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel-bidi- basic-r.lua:178: You cannot set field char in a node of type disc
- All numbers are in English, I need numbers to appear either in accordance with its context (English with English text, Arabic with Arabic text) or in accordance with the main language which is Arabic (It would be good to know how both options work)
- English citations are not left aligned
- In the footers and headers settings made by `fancyhdr`, I set it so that chapter names appear before page numbers, I need the same numbering style to appear in the table of contents.
- I have set the chapter names to appear in letters not in numbers but in Arabic. However, in header, it says `Chapter1`, not `Chapter One`.

Here is an MWE, it is a bit long, but I need to make sure no package conflict will appear upon reaching a solution:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
%General Settings
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{subfiles}  
%==================== ============================================================================
% Fonts%
%==================== ============================================================================
\usepackage{arabluatex}
\usepackage{mathpazo}  
\usepackage{microtype}  
%==================== ============================================================================
% Layout: Paragraphing - section titles, Items%
%==================== ============================================================================
% Paragraphing
\usepackage{indentfirst}  
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}  
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}  
%Section titles
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}  

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}  
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}

% Text layout
\usepackage{multicol}  
\usepackage{ulem}  
% Items
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt}  

\usepackage{rotating}  



%=================================================================================================
%Graphics - pictures - symbols
%=================================================================================================
\usepackage{pifont} 
\usepackage{textcomp}  

\usepackage{url,graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}{../images/}}  


\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows,positioning,matrix,quotes, shapes.geometric,calc}  



\usepackage[breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}  

\newtcolorbox{hl}{%
  frame empty, sharp corners, top=0pt, right=0pt, bottom=0pt, left=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt, toprule=0pt, rightrule=0pt, bottomrule=0pt, leftrule=0pt,
  colback=lightgray, fontupper=\bfseries,
  before upper=\selectlanguage{arabic}%
    {\color{white}\vrule width 1.5em},
  after upper={{\color{white}\leaders\vrule\hfill\null}},
  before=\noindent\begingroup\selectlanguage{english},after=\endgroup,
}

%Set New command for inserting a page border%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{eso-pic} % use it along with the "etoolbox" package for page border
\newcommand{\insertpageborder}{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \draw[line width = 4pt] ($(current page.north west) + (1in,-1in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-1in,1in)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}}}


%==================================================================================================
%CROSS-Referencing
%==================================================================================================

\usepackage[%
  hidelinks,
  colorlinks=true,
  allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 


 \usepackage{tocbibind}  
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}  
\usepackage{nomencl}  
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}  

\makeindex
\makeglossaries

%===================================================================================================
%Tabular Environment
%===================================================================================================
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage{booktabs} 






%======================================================================================================
%MAths Environment%
%======================================================================================================
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}[thm]{Definition} 

%======================================================================================================
%Babel Package Settings%
%======================================================================================================

\usepackage{filecontents} 

\begin{filecontents}{babel-syc.ini}
[identification]
charset = utf8
version = 0.1
date = 2019-08-25
name.local = ܠܫܢܐ ܣܘܪܝܝܐ
name.english = Classical Syriac
name.babel = classicalsyriac
tag.bcp47 = syc
tag.opentype = SYR
script.name = Syriac
script.tag.bcp47 = Syrc
script.tag.opentype = syrc
level = 1
encodings = 
derivate = no
[captions]
[date.gregorian]
[date.islamic]
[time.gregorian]
[typography]
[characters]
[numbers]
[counters]
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{babel-cop.ini}
[identification]
charset = utf8
version = 0.1
date = 2019-08-25
name.local = ϯⲙⲉⲧⲣⲉⲙⲛ̀ⲭⲏⲙⲓ
name.english = Coptic
name.babel = coptic
tag.bcp47 = cop
tag.opentype = COP
script.name = Coptic
script.tag.bcp47 = Copt
script.tag.opentype = copt
level = 1
encodings = 
derivate = no
[captions]
[date.gregorian]
[date.islamic]
[time.gregorian]
[typography]
[characters]
[numbers]
[counters]
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r,layout=counters]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}
\babelprovide[import=el]{polutonikogreek}
\babelprovide[import=syc]{classicalsyriac}
\babelprovide[import=cop]{coptic}
\babelprovide[import=he]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import=de,language=Default]{German}
\babelprovide[import=fr,language=Default]{French}
\babelprovide[import=hu,language=Default]{Hungarian}
\babelfont{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Simplified Arabic}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Times New Roman}
\babelfont[classicalsyriac]{rm}{Serto Jerusalem}
\babelfont[coptic]{rm}[Language=Default]{FreeSerifAvvaShenouda}
\babelfont[polutonikogreek]{rm}[Language=Default]{Palatino Linotype}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Language=Default]{Ezra SIL}

% Don't need special language settings for Hieroglyphs
%\babelfont{hieroglyphs}{Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs}

%==================================================
%References%
%===================================================

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Sharoni1969,
 author = {ميخائيل، ملاك  and  الشاروني، حبيب},
 date = {1969},
 title = {المرجع فى قواعد اللغة القبطية},
 location = {الاسكندرية},
 publisher = {جمعية مارمينا العجايبي},
 langid = {arabic}
}
@book{Browning1983,
 author = {Browning, Robert},
 date = {1983},
 title = {Medieval and Modern Greek},
 publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
 langid = {english}
}
@misc{CBible2015,
 date = {2015},
 title = {\foreignlanguage{english}{Coptic Bible} الكتاب المقدس القبطي},
 langid = {arabic}
}
@online{Website:Elpenor,
 title = {ELPENOR - Home of the Greek Word - Ellopos},
 date = {2015-05},
 url = {https://www.ellopos.net/elpenor/Default.asp},
 langid = {english}
}
\end{filecontents}



%=============================================================
%BIBLIOGRAPHY SETTINGS%
%=============================================================


\begin{filecontents}{arabic.lbx}
\ProvidesFile{arabic.lbx}
\InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
% Translations thanks to Google Translate.
% I haven't provided abbreviations, because I don't know Arabic.
% You'll need to add more for other strings you use.
% Look in `english.lbx` for the string name.
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit          = {english},
  and              = {{و}{و}},
  page             = {{صفحة}{صفحة}},
  pages            = {{صفحات}{صفحة}},
  references       = {{مراجع}{مراجع}},
  seenote          = {{انظر الملاحظة}{انظر الملاحظة}},
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle{arabic}
  {\guillemotleft}
  {\guillemotright}
  {\textquotedblright}
  {\textquotedblleft}



\usepackage[%
  language=auto,
  autolang=other,
  citestyle=verbose-note,
  bibstyle=authortitle,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}  

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item\leavevmode}% add \leavevmode to align English bibliography items RTL

% Always use Arabic digits for see note.
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{footcite:note}
  {\ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}
  {\foreignlanguage{arabic}{\ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
  {}
  {}

% Just to test if quotes work
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibquote{\mkbibemph{#1}}}


%=========================================================================================
%Chapter headings: Naming - Font properties %
%=========================================================================================
% Change chapter heading properties: Centered
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{-30\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \normalfont % centering, ragged right, ragged left
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip -15\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip -15\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{-15\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering % centering, ragged right, ragged left
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip -15\p@
  }}
\makeatother

% Chapter Naming
\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{الباب}} %to name the chapter title   الباب instead of باب
\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\appendixname}{الملحق}} %to name the chapter title   ملحق  instead of ملاحق


 %%%%%  END MACRO Litteral Numbering of chapters 

    \newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
    \def\xwords#1{\ifcase#1\or
    الأول\or
    الثاني\or
    الثالث\or
    الرابع\or
    الخامس\or
    السادس\or
    السابع\or
    الثامن\or
    التاسع\or
    العاشر\or
الحادي عشر\or 
الثاني عشر\or 
الثالث عشر\or 
الرابع عشر\or 
الخامس عشر\or 
السادس عشر\or  
السابع عشر\or
الثامن عشر\or 
التاسع عشر\or 
العشرون\or 
    \else
    I need more words أحتاج إلى المزيد من ترقيمات الأبواب بالحروف في ملف arbbook.cls\fi}
    %%% You can add by the same if there is more then ten chapters

    %next three lines is to make chapter naming use the above wordings (literal numbering in Arabic words)

   \usepackage{etoolbox} %% uncomment if 'etoolbox' isn't already being loaded
    \makeatletter
    \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\words{chapter}}{}{}          
    \makeatother




%%%%%  END MACRO Litteral Numbering of chapters 


%==================================================
%Headers and Foters %
%===================================================



% For header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\rightmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}
\cfoot{\thechapter-\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}

% Set header and footer for other pages than normal ones
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\leftmark}
\cfoot{\thechapter-\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}}







%==================================================
%Start actual document %
%===================================================



%==================================================
%Start actual document %
%===================================================


\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}


\begin{document}


\begin{frontmatter}
\pagenumbering{alph} % Change page numbering from roman to alphabetic

\begin{titlepage} %\maketitle %option titlepage ends the page after \maketitle and restarts on the next page, titel page option is equivalent to \make title + \clearpage

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Suppresses displaying the page number on the title page and the subsequent page counts as page 1
    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for horizontal lines, change thickness here

    \center % Centre everything on the page



    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Page Border
    %------------------------------------------------



                     \insertpageborder





    %------------------------------------------------
    %   First Figure
    %------------------------------------------------
        \centering{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{F-0_1}}

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Headings
    %------------------------------------------------

    \textsc{\LARGE gfdfdgdfg}\\[1.5cm] % Main heading such as the name of your university/college

    \textsc{\Large fgdfgdfgfdg}\\[0.5cm] % Major heading such as course name

    \textsc{\large fdgfdgfdgfg}\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title

    \textsc{\large gfdgfdgfdgfdg}\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Title
    %------------------------------------------------

    \HRule\\[0.4cm]

    {\huge\bfseries
dffddf \\
dffddfdf}\\ 
                                [0.4cm] % Title of your document                                    
    \HRule\\[0.4cm]


    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Second Figure
    %------------------------------------------------


        \centering{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{F-0_2}}



    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Author(s)
    %------------------------------------------------

    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{flushleft}
            \large
            \textit{cxzxcxzcxzc}\\
            B.J. \textsc{Blazkowicz} % Your name
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    ~
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{flushright}
            \large
            \textit{bvcbvcb}\\
            Dr. Caroline \textsc{Becker} % Supervisor's name
        \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}

    % If you don't want a supervisor, uncomment the two lines below and comment the code above
    %{\large\textit{Author}}\\
    %John \textsc{Smith} % Your name

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Date
    %------------------------------------------------

    \vfill\vfill\vfill % Position the date 3/4 down the remaining page

    {\large\today} % Date, change the \today to a set date if you want to be precise

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Logo
    %------------------------------------------------

    %\vfill\vfill
    %\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{1-ARCHANGEL}\\[1cm] % Include a department/university logo - this will require the graphicx package

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \vfill % Push the date up 1/4 of the remaining page






\end{titlepage}










\tableofcontents
\end{frontmatter}


\chapter{سسسييسسييس}

\section{ مقدمة}

\section{مقدمة عن تاريخ الكتابة المصرية القديمة}


\section{مقدمة عن تاريخ الكتابة المصرية القديمة}

\section{مقدمة عن تاريخ الكتابة المصرية القديمة}


. حيث حُذِفَت علامة الرفع (وس) وايضاً حُذِفَت الحركة الأولى (أي) والتي ظنها العرب استهلال يتبقى اسم قبط
\footcites[13]{Sharoni1969}[2]{Browning1983}



وهى مأخوذة من "حام" بن نوح
\footcite[12-13]{CBible2015}
سيبيسبيسبسيب
\footcite[12-13]{Website:Elpenor}
سيبيسبيسبسيب
\footcite{Browning1983}
بيلبيلبيلبيلبيلبيل
\footcites[13]{Sharoni1969}
\newpage
\printbibliography
\printbibliography[keyword={Arabic},title={المراجع العربية},heading=subbibliography]
{
  \selectlanguage{english}
  \printbibliography[keyword={English}, title={ُEnglish References}, heading=subbibliography]
}



\end{document}
```

[image: 1]
[image: 3]
[image]
[image]

Comment: While it is understable that you want to solve all your issues in one go: I won't investigate such a long document with 5-6 issues. This takes too much time.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, the problem is that the OP has asked several questions already that I've answered, but having trouble integrating things. (Though Silva, you have missed stuff from my most recent answer.)

Comment: @Silva, you change the page numbering to `alph` after `\frontmatter` and never change things after that. I thought you wanted chapter-page format in arabic numbers?

Comment: Your first point is fixable by setting up the footers in the right way

Comment: For me, numbers appear in Arabic everywhere except when the language is English

Comment: For English citations, do you mean the footnote should *start* on the left hand side? Should they be numbered with English numbers? What should happen when you use `\footcites` and one reference is in English and the other in Arabic?

Comment: For your last point, you haven't included my changes from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/505715/87678

Comment: Your syntax for frontmatter is wrong. It should be `\frontmatter` … `\mainmatter`. (No begin and end).

Comment: @ David: "you change the page numbering to alph after \frontmatter and never change things after that. I thought you wanted chapter-page format in arabic numbers" I am supposed to have alphabetic numbering in front matter and chapter page format in the rest of the document. This coding used to work with the "Polyglyossia + XELATEX", I didn't think that changing from polyglyossia to babel might require changes in the code regarding page layout

Comment: @David: The first issue is avoided throught using the header and footer definitions shown in: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504667/section-names-and-page-numbers-do-not-appear-correctly/505715#505715

Comment: @ David: English references are to be aligned on LHS, While Arabic ones are to be aligned on RHS. While numbering is to be done with the main document language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gives pretty close to what you want.

I'm just not sure what you mean by English citations should be left aligned and how practical this is if you mix an Arabic and and English citation in the same footnote.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
%General Settings
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{subfiles}  
%==================== ============================================================================
% Fonts%
%==================== ============================================================================
\usepackage{arabluatex}
\usepackage{mathpazo}  
\usepackage{microtype}  
%==================== ============================================================================
% Layout: Paragraphing - section titles, Items%
%==================== ============================================================================
% Paragraphing
\usepackage{indentfirst}  
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}  
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}  
%Section titles
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}  

\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}  
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}

% Text layout
\usepackage{multicol}  
\usepackage{ulem}  
% Items
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt}  

\usepackage{rotating}  



%=================================================================================================
%Graphics - pictures - symbols
%=================================================================================================
\usepackage{pifont} 
\usepackage{textcomp}  

\usepackage{url,graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}{../images/}}  


\usepackage{tikz}  
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows,positioning,matrix,quotes, shapes.geometric,calc}  



\usepackage[breakable,skins]{tcolorbox}  

\newtcolorbox{hl}{%
  frame empty, sharp corners, top=0pt, right=0pt, bottom=0pt, left=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt, toprule=0pt, rightrule=0pt, bottomrule=0pt, leftrule=0pt,
  colback=lightgray, fontupper=\bfseries,
  before upper=\selectlanguage{arabic}%
    {\color{white}\vrule width 1.5em},
  after upper={{\color{white}\leaders\vrule\hfill\null}},
  before=\noindent\begingroup\selectlanguage{english},after=\endgroup,
}

%Set New command for inserting a page border%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{eso-pic} % use it along with the "etoolbox" package for page border
\newcommand{\insertpageborder}{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \draw[line width = 4pt] ($(current page.north west) + (1in,-1in)$) rectangle ($(current page.south east) + (-1in,1in)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}}}


%==================================================================================================
%CROSS-Referencing
%==================================================================================================

\usepackage[%
  hidelinks,
  colorlinks=true,
  allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 


 \usepackage{tocbibind}  
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}  
\usepackage{nomencl}  
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}  

\makeindex
\makeglossaries

%===================================================================================================
%Tabular Environment
%===================================================================================================
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage{booktabs} 






%======================================================================================================
%MAths Environment%
%======================================================================================================
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}[thm]{Definition} 

%======================================================================================================
%Babel Package Settings%
%======================================================================================================

\usepackage{filecontents} 

\begin{filecontents}{babel-syc.ini}
[identification]
charset = utf8
version = 0.1
date = 2019-08-25
name.local = ܠܫܢܐ ܣܘܪܝܝܐ
name.english = Classical Syriac
name.babel = classicalsyriac
tag.bcp47 = syc
tag.opentype = SYR
script.name = Syriac
script.tag.bcp47 = Syrc
script.tag.opentype = syrc
level = 1
encodings = 
derivate = no
[captions]
[date.gregorian]
[date.islamic]
[time.gregorian]
[typography]
[characters]
[numbers]
[counters]
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{babel-cop.ini}
[identification]
charset = utf8
version = 0.1
date = 2019-08-25
name.local = ϯⲙⲉⲧⲣⲉⲙⲛ̀ⲭⲏⲙⲓ
name.english = Coptic
name.babel = coptic
tag.bcp47 = cop
tag.opentype = COP
script.name = Coptic
script.tag.bcp47 = Copt
script.tag.opentype = copt
level = 1
encodings = 
derivate = no
[captions]
[date.gregorian]
[date.islamic]
[time.gregorian]
[typography]
[characters]
[numbers]
[counters]
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r,layout=counters.lists]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}
\babelprovide[import=el]{polutonikogreek}
\babelprovide[import=syc]{classicalsyriac}
\babelprovide[import=cop]{coptic}
\babelprovide[import=he]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import=de,language=Default]{German}
\babelprovide[import=fr,language=Default]{French}
\babelprovide[import=hu,language=Default]{Hungarian}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}
\babelfont{rm}{Times New Roman}
\babelfont[classicalsyriac]{rm}{Noto Sans Syriac}
\babelfont[coptic]{rm}[Language=Default]{Noto Sans Coptic}
\babelfont[polutonikogreek]{rm}[Language=Default]{Noto Serif}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Language=Default]{Ezra SIL}

% Don't need special language settings for Hieroglyphs
%\babelfont{hieroglyphs}{Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs}

%==================================================
%References%
%===================================================

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Sharoni1969,
 author = {ميخائيل، ملاك  and  الشاروني، حبيب},
 date = {1969},
 title = {المرجع فى قواعد اللغة القبطية},
 location = {الاسكندرية},
 publisher = {جمعية مارمينا العجايبي},
 langid = {arabic},
 keywords = {Arabic}
}
@book{Browning1983,
 author = {Browning, Robert},
 date = {1983},
 title = {Medieval and Modern Greek},
 publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
 langid = {english},
 keywords = {English}
}
@misc{CBible2015,
 date = {2015},
 title = {\foreignlanguage{english}{Coptic Bible} الكتاب المقدس القبطي},
 langid = {arabic},
 keywords = {Arabic}
}
@online{Website:Elpenor,
 title = {ELPENOR - Home of the Greek Word - Ellopos},
 date = {2015-05},
 url = {https://www.ellopos.net/elpenor/Default.asp},
 langid = {english},
 keywords = {English}
}
\end{filecontents}



%=============================================================
%BIBLIOGRAPHY SETTINGS%
%=============================================================


\begin{filecontents}{arabic.lbx}
\ProvidesFile{arabic.lbx}
\InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
% Translations thanks to Google Translate.
% I haven't provided abbreviations, because I don't know Arabic.
% You'll need to add more for other strings you use.
% Look in `english.lbx` for the string name.
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit          = {english},
  and              = {{و}{و}},
  page             = {{صفحة}{صفحة}},
  pages            = {{صفحات}{صفحة}},
  references       = {{مراجع}{مراجع}},
  seenote          = {{انظر الملاحظة}{انظر الملاحظة}},
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle{arabic}
  {\guillemotleft}
  {\guillemotright}
  {\textquotedblright}
  {\textquotedblleft}



\usepackage[%
  language=auto,
  autolang=other,
  citestyle=verbose-note,
  bibstyle=authortitle,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}  

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item\leavevmode}% add \leavevmode to align English bibliography items RTL

% Always use Arabic digits for see note.
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{footcite:note}
  {\ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}
  {\foreignlanguage{arabic}{\ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
  {}
  {}

% Just to test if quotes work
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibquote{\mkbibemph{#1}}}


%=========================================================================================
%Chapter headings: Naming - Font properties %
%=========================================================================================
% Change chapter heading properties: Centered
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{-30\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \normalfont % centering, ragged right, ragged left
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip -15\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip -15\p@
  }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{-15\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering % centering, ragged right, ragged left
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip -15\p@
  }}
\makeatother

% Chapter Naming
\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{الباب}} %to name the chapter title   الباب instead of باب
\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\appendixname}{الملحق}} %to name the chapter title   ملحق  instead of ملاحق


 %%%%%  END MACRO Litteral Numbering of chapters 

    \newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
    \def\xwords#1{\ifcase#1\or
    الأول\or
    الثاني\or
    الثالث\or
    الرابع\or
    الخامس\or
    السادس\or
    السابع\or
    الثامن\or
    التاسع\or
    العاشر\or
الحادي عشر\or 
الثاني عشر\or 
الثالث عشر\or 
الرابع عشر\or 
الخامس عشر\or 
السادس عشر\or  
السابع عشر\or
الثامن عشر\or 
التاسع عشر\or 
العشرون\or 
    \else
    I need more words أحتاج إلى المزيد من ترقيمات الأبواب بالحروف في ملف arbbook.cls\fi}
    %%% You can add by the same if there is more then ten chapters

    %next three lines is to make chapter naming use the above wordings (literal numbering in Arabic words)

\usepackage{etoolbox} %% uncomment if 'etoolbox' isn't already being loaded

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\Hy@org@chapter}
  {\begingroup \renewcommand{\thechapter}{{\words{chapter}}}}
  {}
  {}
\apptocmd{\Hy@org@chapter}
  {\endgroup}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
  {\thechapter}
  {\words{chapter}}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother




%%%%%  END MACRO Litteral Numbering of chapters 


%==================================================
%Headers and Foters %
%===================================================



% For header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pagenumberingchappage}{%
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\thechapter-\csname @arabic\endcsname\c@page}}
\makeatother

% Set header and footer for other pages than normal ones
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}}







%==================================================
%Start actual document %
%===================================================



%==================================================
%Start actual document %
%===================================================


\title{jhhjjhhj}
\author{}
\date{}


\begin{document}


\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{alph} % Change page numbering from roman to alphabetic

\begin{titlepage} %\maketitle %option titlepage ends the page after \maketitle and restarts on the next page, titel page option is equivalent to \make title + \clearpage

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Suppresses displaying the page number on the title page and the subsequent page counts as page 1
    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for horizontal lines, change thickness here

    \center % Centre everything on the page



    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Page Border
    %------------------------------------------------



                     \insertpageborder





    %------------------------------------------------
    %   First Figure
    %------------------------------------------------
        \centering{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a.jpg}}

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Headings
    %------------------------------------------------

    \textsc{\LARGE gfdfdgdfg}\\[1.5cm] % Main heading such as the name of your university/college

    \textsc{\Large fgdfgdfgfdg}\\[0.5cm] % Major heading such as course name

    \textsc{\large fdgfdgfdgfg}\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title

    \textsc{\large gfdgfdgfdgfdg}\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Title
    %------------------------------------------------

    \HRule\\[0.4cm]

    {\huge\bfseries
dffddf \\
dffddfdf}\\ 
                                [0.4cm] % Title of your document                                    
    \HRule\\[0.4cm]


    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Second Figure
    %------------------------------------------------


        \centering{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-b.jpg}}



    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Author(s)
    %------------------------------------------------

    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{flushleft}
            \large
            \textit{cxzxcxzcxzc}\\
            B.J. \textsc{Blazkowicz} % Your name
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    ~
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{flushright}
            \large
            \textit{bvcbvcb}\\
            Dr. Caroline \textsc{Becker} % Supervisor's name
        \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}

    % If you don't want a supervisor, uncomment the two lines below and comment the code above
    %{\large\textit{Author}}\\
    %John \textsc{Smith} % Your name

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Date
    %------------------------------------------------

    \vfill\vfill\vfill % Position the date 3/4 down the remaining page

    {\large\today} % Date, change the \today to a set date if you want to be precise

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Logo
    %------------------------------------------------

    %\vfill\vfill
    %\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{1-ARCHANGEL}\\[1cm] % Include a department/university logo - this will require the graphicx package

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \vfill % Push the date up 1/4 of the remaining page






\end{titlepage}










\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\pagenumberingchappage



\chapter{سسسييسسييس}

\section{ مقدمة}

\section{مقدمة عن تاريخ الكتابة المصرية القديمة}


\section{مقدمة عن تاريخ الكتابة المصرية القديمة}

\clearpage

\section{مقدمة عن تاريخ الكتابة المصرية القديمة}


. حيث حُذِفَت علامة الرفع (وس) وايضاً حُذِفَت الحركة الأولى (أي) والتي ظنها العرب استهلال يتبقى اسم قبط
\footcites[13]{Sharoni1969}[2]{Browning1983}



وهى مأخوذة من "حام" بن نوح
\footcite[12-13]{CBible2015}
سيبيسبيسبسيب
\footcite[12-13]{Website:Elpenor}
سيبيسبيسبسيب
\footcite{Browning1983}
بيلبيلبيلبيلبيلبيل
\footcites[13]{Sharoni1969}
\newpage
\printbibliography
\printbibliography[keyword={Arabic},title={المراجع العربية},heading=subbibliography]

\selectlanguage{english}

\printbibliography[keyword={English}, title={English References}, heading=subbibliography]




\end{document}
```

Comment: @ David, THX, issues resolved, only one final comment@ https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81692/not-having-chapter-appear-in-chapter-names, although still all numbers appear as English and bookmarks in pdf file appear as strange characters. Sorry for your annoyance, However, I am new to latex, I have been using MS word and trying to shift.